# How Use shared preference with injectable and get_it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies, injectable

im using injectable and get_it package in flutter
i have a shared preference class :

```
@LazySingleton()
class SharedPref {
  final String _token = 'token';
  SharedPreferences _pref;

  SharedPref(this._pref);

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    return _pref.getString(_token) ?? '';
  }

  Future<void> setToken(String token) async {
    await _pref.setString(_token, token);
  }
}
```

this class inject as **LazySingleton** and i have a module for inject the shared preference :

```
@module
abstract class InjectableModule {

 @lazySingleton
 Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs => SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

in bloc class im using SharedPref class :

```
@injectable
class LoginCheckBloc extends Bloc<LoginCheckEvent, LoginCheckState> {
  final SharedPref sharedPref;

  LoginCheckBloc({@required this.sharedPref}) : super(const LoginCheckState.initial());

  @override
  Stream<LoginCheckState> mapEventToState(
    LoginCheckEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is CheckLogin) {
      final String token = await sharedPref.getToken();
      if (token.isEmpty){
        yield const LoginCheckState.notLogin();
      }else{
        yield const LoginCheckState.successLogin();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i use LoginCheckBloc with getIt<> i have an error for injecting the shared prefrence :

```
BlocProvider<LoginCheckBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => getIt<LoginCheckBloc>()..add(CheckLogin()),
        ),
```

the error message is :

```
You tried to access an instance of SharedPreferences that was not ready yet
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 272 pos 14: 'instanceFactory.isReady'
```

how use shared preference with injectable ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It worked on mine when I used `@preResolve` the `SharedPreference`

```
@module
abstract class InjectableModule{

 @preResolve
 Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs => SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 
}
```

and then on the injectable class you write this

```
final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
Future<void> configureInjection(String env) async {
 await $initGetIt(getIt, environment: env);
}
```

and on the main class

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await configureInjection(Environment.prod);
 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I was able to solve it by wrapping `runApp()` with `GetIt.I.isReady<SharedPreferences>()`.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  GetIt.I.isReady<SharedPreferences>().then((_) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello. What if I have more than one async instance. Can I put them in a list or something like this?

Comment: @MU'menAhmed Maybe you can nest the `isReady` functions, then you can have the app runs only when all the instances are ready.

Comment: you can use allReady instead of isReady