# Flutter dependency injenction with shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences, injectable

Good evening,
I'm trying to use dependency injection with the shared preferences plugin, but as soon is I generate the code, I get an error for an unrelated Bloc.
I use

- GetIt: ^0.5.3,
- injectable_generator: 1.0.6
- flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1.

My Goal is to inject SharedPreferences into a class for handling local operations, it looks like that:

```dart
class LocalSharedPreferences {
 final SharedPreferences _preferences;

 LocalSharedPreferences(this._preferences);
 ...
}
```

In order to inject SharedPreferences properly, I followed its official documentation (https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#registering-asynchronous-injectables), thus my code to inject a 3rd-party module looks like this:

```dart
@module
abstract class RegisterModule {
  @preResolve
  Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs => SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62978048/how-use-shared-preference-with-injectable-and-get-it-in-flutter) question on StackOverflow but it did not work. My error is as follows:

```dart
The following assertion was thrown building SignInForm(dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
Object/factory with  type SignInFormBloc is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do  GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 9: 'instanceFactory != null'
```

The auto-generated-injection code looks like follows:

```dart
Future<GetIt> $initGetIt(
  GetIt get, {
  String environment,
  EnvironmentFilter environmentFilter,
}) async {
  final gh = GetItHelper(get, environment, environmentFilter);
  final registerModule = _$RegisterModule();
  gh.factory<DatosBauServerApiHelper>(() => DatosBauServerApiHelper());
  gh.factory<DatosBauServerAuth>(
      () => DatosBauServerAuth(get<DatosBauServerApiHelper>()));
  gh.lazySingleton<IAuthFacade>(
      () => DatosBauServerAuthFacade(get<DatosBauServerAuth>()));
  final sharedPreferences = await registerModule.prefs;
  gh.factory<SharedPreferences>(() => sharedPreferences);
  gh.factory<SignInFormBloc>(() => SignInFormBloc(get<IAuthFacade>()));
  return get;
}

class _$RegisterModule extends RegisterModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package [Get it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

LocalSharedPreferences class

```
abstract class LocalSharedPreferences {
   // ...
}
```

LocalSharedPreferencesImpl class

```
class LocalSharedPreferencesImpl extends LocalSharedPreferences {
   // ...
   // Use your globalSharedPrefs variable here
}
```

Another dart file

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

setupServicesLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<LocalSharedPreferences>(() => LocalSharedPreferencesImpl());
}
```

Your main.dart file

```
SharedPreferences globalSharedPrefs;

void main() async {
  /* ENSURE ASYNC WILL NOT GENERATE RUNTIME ERROR */
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  /* GLOBAL SERVICES */
  setupServicesLocator();

  /* Initialize your globalSharedPreferences variable here */
  globalSharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```